# Preload Key Request - Improving css calls

Tags: css, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I am trying to improve the load speed of a website by following Goggle's PageSpeed Insights recommendations. One of the main issues I need to fix is the following:
[image: PageSpeed Insights recommendations]

The webpage calls this css file:

"link rel="stylesheet" href="https:.../main.css"

and the main.css file calls the bootstrap.css file:

In main.css:
@import url('bootstrap.css');

I tried reading google's developer guide on link rel=preload but I still cannot figure out what changes I need to make.
Any recommendations on how I could change my css calls to improve the page load time?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the `<head>` of the document you simply need to add a meta tag telling the browser to preload the font.

`<link rel="preload" href="yoursite.com/bootstrap.css"  as="style" crossorigin>`

This needs to appear before any style sheet links you may have.

The key parts are `as="style"` and `rel="preload"` - `crossorigin` may be needed if you utilise a CDN etc.

It does not matter that it is a linked CSS file, it will still work.

Do exactly the same for your `main.css` file as well.